# Autohotkey and Azerty: how to remap §,è,ç,à keys without remapping the numbers?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remap

In order to program more efficiently, I want to remap some seldomly used keys on my azerty keyboard §èçà to the more useful []{} (Which otherwise need a Alt-Gr).

I tried a script like this

```
§::{
è::}
ç::[
à::]
```

But the problem is that Autohotkey automatically also maps the shifted keys; as such I lose my numbers. Adding the following script does not seem to solve the issue:

```
 +§::6
 +è::7
 +ç::9
 +à::0
```

Any help how I might remap the "lowercase" letters but not the "uppercase" numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:
This looks for a string of one character and the capital C makes it case sensitive. Since I don't own a azerty keyboard, I can't test it.

```
:?C*:§::{{}
:?C*:è::{}}
:?C*:ç::{[}
:?C*:à::{]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
#If !GetKeyState("LShift") && !GetKeyState("RShift")
§::{
è::}
ç::[
à::]
```

Comment: This code also seems to do the trick, and is, hence, also correct.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
:?C*:§::{{}
:?C*:è::{}}
:?C*:ç::{[}
:?C*:à::{]}
```

although my version is

```
:?C*:ù::{[}
:?C*:µ::{]}
:?C*:ç::{{}
:?C*:à::{}}
```